# If A, B are independent from C, then does it follow that B is independent from C

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Consider 3 random variables, A B and C. If A, B are independent from C, then does it follow that B is independent from C if so, how can we show this?

Comment: Are you talking about events or random variables?

Comment: Random variables, I'll edit to clarify

Comment: And the meaning of the comma?  Is this "If $A$ is independent from $C$, and $B$ is independent from $C$"  then obviously $B$ would be independent from $C$, it is after all the second half of the statement in the premise.  Do you mean instead $(A\cap B)$ *is* independent from $C$?  In that case, no.  Consider $B$ and $C$ dependent and $A$ the impossible event.

Comment: If you don't like examples with the impossible event, then consider $A$ and $C$ independent, neither occurring with probabilities 0 or 1, and $B$ a super event of $A$, also not occurring with probability $1$.  For example when rolling an 8 sided die $A=\{1,2,3,4\},B=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $C=\{2,4,6,8\}$

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Since you indicate they are random variables, I prefer to use the symbols of $X, Y$ and $Z$. That is if $X, Y$ are independent of $Z$, does it follow that $Y$ is independent of $Z$? The answer is YES. There are multiple ways to prove this rigorously. But fundamentally it is because if $\sigma(Z)$ is independent of $\sigma(X, Y)$, then $\sigma(Z)$ is independent of any sub-$\sigma$ algebra of $\sigma(X, Y)$, and $\sigma(Y) \subset \sigma(X, Y).$

Comment: Okay, I think I understand the fundamental premise, but I'm kinda fuzzy on how I'd go about showing this using probability algebra. e.g showing P(X,Y)P(Z) = P(Y)P(Z), I believe this is what we'd need to show, yes?

Comment: I feel you are not looking for a rigorous theoretical proof. In the classical sense, you can follow the following line of arguments with probability density functions (if they exist): Let $X, Y$ has joint density $g(x, y)$, then $X$ has $f(x) = \int g(x, y)dy$. The Independence assumption gives $h(x, y, z)=g(x, y)s(z)$. Hence $p(x, z) = \int h(x, y, z)dy = \int g(x, y)s(z)dy = f(x)s(z)$. Hence $X, Z$ are independent.

Answer (score 0):

For random variables, $A,B\perp C$ means that *for all* measureable subsets $\Sigma,\Delta,\Gamma$  of the variables' supports:

$$\mathsf P(A\in\Sigma, B\in\Delta,C\in\Gamma)=\mathsf P(A\in\Sigma, B\in\Delta)\cdot\mathsf P(C\in\Gamma)$$

Now as this is true *for all* subsets, ...